# unity-lens-music takes long time to retrieve information from hdd

Tags: 12.04, unity, music, lenses

Everytime I open the dash and go to the music lens to search for a specific title, it takes quite a while till any titles are displayed and I can hear my hdd working during the process.

I didn't copy too many of my CDs to my laptop so I don't really get why it takes the lens so long to load any matches.

Is there a way to make the lens search from a customized database? Or does it use an approach like that by default?

After reading the whole music library once the lens works really snappy and instantly displays titles. Sadly everytime I reboot and go back to the lens it again takes much longer to display any results, as if it needs to build a new database after every reboot.

Unfortunately I wasn't able to find a lot of information about the music lens and how it works so I ask here.

I'd be happy to get some clarification and maybe a few hints as to whats going wrong.

Comment: Is this still a problem for you?

Comment: I just tested this under Ubuntu 16.04 on `/dev/sdc` where the music-lens is built into dash by default. Response time was near instantaneous finding music on a Windows 7 partition in `/dev/sdb`. Therefore files are pre-indexed and kept in a cache file somewhere. As this unanswered question written 5+ years ago is about Ubuntu 12.04 which is EOL, VTC'ing as `not reproducible`.